# Can I place database of my webapp in a cloud while the webapp itself is residing in some other paid server?

Tags: web-applications, cloud

I have created a webapp that has a lot of database connections in backend. What I want is to place the webapp in a paid server, at the same time the database of the app is to be placed in a cloud. Is this possible? or whether I need to move the whole webapp and database to a cloud?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, sure.

However, you'll have to check carefully latency issues by pinging from one server to another.

Also understand zones, in regards to how various servers in one cloud communicate to the ones in the db cloud.

Generally speaking, it seems best to have DB and APP server close together.

Comment: So can i place the webapp and database in the same cloud?

Comment: Sure. Depends on the service. Amazon has hosting for apps and server, Heroku too has, and actually, must platform have both as part of the offered service.